# Embedding mac font into flex application

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have one font(VinylRegular). This font has extensions (like .ttf, .otf) of PostScript Type 1 outline font. How do I embed such fonts into a Flex application?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to embed fonts, all of them are explained here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html